# Given two equal sized chords, find angle $ABC$

Tags: geometry

Given two chords of equal length that also intersect at a point on the circle, find angle $ABC$ given that angle $AOB = 70$ degrees and the radius is $r$. [My drawn image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMSaG.jpg)

Note that the origin is denote by $O$ and the two chords are denoted as $[AB]$ and $[AC]$

How can we find angle OAB without having an actual value for the radius? Once we have that angle, I think we can continue to find angle BOC and then apply side-angle-side to find angle BOC. Once we have that, we can take the sum BOC + ABO and have our answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triangle $AOB$ as two sides with the same length, $[AO]$ and $[OB]$. Thus the angles $OAB$ and $OBA$, opposite, are equals.  Since angle $AOB = 70$ degrees, the other two are half the remaining, 55 degrees.

Comment: Oh, of course. Then angle $BAC = 110$. Then we get angle $ABC=35$ as our answer. No need for the complicated process I previously thought we needed